# Flutter Bloc test error with late initialize variable?

Tags: flutter, modularization

After i'm running test with bloc test, i got issue late error, if i change late with nullsafety their also will be return error, so what alternative to solve? when i try without bloc it's run as well nothing return error.

```
@GenerateMocks([SearchMovies, SearchTvSeriess])
void main() {
  late SearchMovieBloc searchMovieBloc;
  late SearchTvSeriesBloc searchTvSeriesBloc;
  late MockSearchMovies mockSearchMovies;
  late MockSearchTvSeriess mockSearchTvSeriess;

  setUp(() {
    searchTvSeriesBloc = SearchTvSeriesBloc(mockSearchTvSeriess);
    mockSearchMovies = MockSearchMovies();
    searchMovieBloc = SearchMovieBloc(mockSearchMovies);
    mockSearchTvSeriess = MockSearchTvSeriess();
  });

  final tTvSeriesModel = TvSeries(
      originalName: "2 Good 2 Be True",
      posterPath: "/2Wf5ySCPcnp8lRhbSD7jt0YLz5A.jpg",
      id: 135647,
      overview:
          "Car mechanic Eloy makes a terrible first impression on Ali, who works for a real estate magnate. But both of them are hiding their true personas.",
      popularity: 943.32,
      genreIds: [35, 18],
      backdropPath: "/sIRK4NYe1OK2hOJAg4xxuxzceKk.jpg",
      voteAverage: 7.5,
      voteCount: 102);
  final tTvSeriesList = <TvSeries>[tTvSeriesModel];
  final tQuery = 'spiderman';

  group('Search Movies', () {
    test('Initial state should be empty', () {
      expect(searchMovieBloc.state, SearchEmpty(''));
    });

    blocTest<SearchMovieBloc, SearchState>(
      'Should emit [SearchLoading, SearchHasData] when data is gotten successfully',
      build: () {
        when(mockSearchMovies.execute(tQuery))
            .thenAnswer((_) async => Right(testMovieList));
        return searchMovieBloc;
      },
      act: (bloc) => bloc.add(OnQueryChanged(tQuery)),
      wait: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
      expect: () => [
        SearchLoading(),
        SearchHasData(testMovieList),
      ],
      verify: (bloc) {
        verify(mockSearchMovies.execute(tQuery));
      },
    );
```

[issue's pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WC7Ip.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem that you are initializing bloc in setup before its dependancies. The order matters here. Maybe you should do it like this:

```
setUp(() {
   mockSearchTvSeriess = MockSearchTvSeriess();
   mockSearchMovies = MockSearchMovies();
   searchTvSeriesBloc = SearchTvSeriesBloc(mockSearchTvSeriess);
   searchMovieBloc = SearchMovieBloc(mockSearchMovies);
});
```

Comment: i got solve this problem because my bloc test is old, so i change version

Comment: i got error again, same error, i don't know what is wrong with this package